# align jupyter notebook tables to the left

Tags: latex, jupyter-notebook

When I create a simple table in Jupyter Notebooks, the table appears in the center of the cell.  What do I have to do to align that table to the left instead of center?

Sample Latex Table for Jupyter:

```
| This | is   |
|------|------|
|   a  | table|
```

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

When creating a table and assigning it the float: left attribute you end up having to add more CSS to resolve the text that surrounds the table. Place this in a code cell before your markdown cell

```
%%html
<style>
    table {
        display: inline-block
    }
</style>
```

However, if you have a lot of CSS, might be best to put it in another file for the overall beauty of the document.

Comment: Good tip. I was originally using `float: left`, which on occasion, had some unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 6):

Here are the steps:

- Create a Code cell just above your markdown cell where you want to show your table.
- Write the following in your Code cell.

> ```
> %%html
> <style>
> table {float:left}
> </style>
> ```

- Run your Code cell.
- Write Table markdown code in your Markdown cell. Your table should now align to the left.

Comment: Nice, but this creates a formatting cell in my Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Align tables only for markdown output:

Jupyter & Jupyter Lab:

```
%%html
<style>
    /* Jupyter */
    .rendered_html table,
    /* Jupyter Lab*/
    div[data-mime-type="text-markdown"] table {
        margin-left: 0
    }
</style>
```

Put this code once on the top of notebook in Code cell